# Arquivos INC no include do PHP

Tags: php, estilo-de-codificação

É uma boa prática utilizar arquivos `.inc` no `include` do PHP? Ou tanto faz a extensão?

```
<?php include("base.inc") ?> 
<?php include("base.php") ?>
```

Comment: O "problema" de fato é que boa parte dos editores de código não vão mais tratar o source como PHP. Pode fazer o inverso, usar .php como include, e sem extensão e .htm como PHP (foi exemplo). Seja como for, mantenha os .inc (a extensão que for pra include) como inacessível para acesso direto (totalmente bloqueado, tanto para execução quanto servir como texto), e procure por sempre fora da raiz do site. Ainda, estude a diferença entre include e require, e as variantes include_once e require_once. De qualquer forma, não é uma pergunta que tenha "resposta certa". Depende só do contexto de cada um.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para incluir o arquivo tanto faz a extensão. PHP não diferencia nada.

Mas pode ter um problema na configuração do servidor HTTP (Apache, IIS ou outro) que não dá tratamento especial para esta extensão, se der adequadamente nada terá problema.

O servidor web processa de forma diferente arquivos com determinada extensão, por exemplo o `.php` que é mandado para o PHP executar em vez dele entregar o arquivo pura e simplesmente para o cliente que pediu, e depois de processado o resultado é entregue para o cliente e não o arquivo que deve ter um código PHP.

Esse arquivo `.inc` provavelmente tem código PHP também. Mesmo que ele não seja invocado diretamente e nunca seja chamado pelo servidor em condições normais ele poderia ser chamado por alguém fora do que você planejou no seu site e o código seria exposto. Se o servidor mandar chamar o PHP em vez de entregar o código até para esta extensão esse risco não existe. melhor ainda nem deixar o servidor entregar este arquivo.

Então garanta que está tudo ok configurando o seu servidor HTTP para impedir o acesso a estas extensões.

Eu vejo mais as pessoas usando `.php` mesmo e para diferenciar que é um arquivo de inclusão fica em uma pasta chamada `includes`. Então esta seria a "prática" que alguns consideram boa. O que importa é a prática ser correta e segura, "boa" é subjetivo e depende de contexto. Eu não vejo muitos problemas nisso (a não ser que seu código gere problemas por ser executado sozinho), mas o mais correto seria nem deixar o arquivo ser executado.